# Facing error while reading MySQL table in Sqoop. using Sqoop Eval

Tags: java, jdbc, avro, sqoop

```
h-user@h-primary:~/sqoop-1.4.7/bin$ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/HADOOP_BANK_DATA_POC --username root --password xxxxxxxx --query "select * from E_INFO"
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/h-user/sqoop-1.4.7/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2366: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2461: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: invalid variable name
2022-12-23 17:13:06,493 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2022-12-23 17:13:06,683 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/LogicalType
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory.accept(DefaultManagerFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory.getManager(ConnFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.init(BaseSqoopTool.java:272)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.EvalSqlTool.run(EvalSqlTool.java:56)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.LogicalType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 10 more
h-user@h-primary:~/s
```

Trying to read mysql table and databases in sqoop using eval when executed getting above error.
i tried outside of bin also,still same error.whats going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop will create Avro schema files for the table when it imports data. You'd need to add Avro JARs to the Sqoop `lib` directory (the tool classpath).

By the way, you should use `--table E_INFO` instead of `--query "select * FROM E_INFO"`

See docs on controlling data format - https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose

**NOTE**: As answered before, Sqoop is a retired Apache project. Suggest you find an alternative tool that will be maintained going forward.

Comment: this solved the Avro schema error, but now am getting another error.

Comment: Such as? And why continue to use Sqoop at all?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils - i tried adding org-apache-common-langs2.6.jar still its shows the same error.

Comment: actually, am doing it for a small poc and want to finish rest dependencies. once this is implemented, I will change it later with new tool.

Comment: That should be the correct JAR. Even as a POC, you should use tools that you'll actually use when deployed for real